# Using Google Site Verification API in Django on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-site-verification-api

I have a Django app running on Python 3.

I want to use Google Site Verification API to let users prove to me that they own a certain site.

What's a good way to do that? Obviously, I'd like to use ready-made packages whenever possible and write the least amount of code that I can.

Comment: is the somthing similar you are looking out for https://github.com/nkuttler/django-webmaster-verification

Comment: @bhushya: No, it looks like the package you linked to is used to verify that your own site is yours, while I want to allow my *users* to verify that a certain site is theirs. (Using Google's oAuth2 service for it.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any eligable package solution for your needs.

We've added field to model Site 'google_verification', as optional.
Then, in your very base template,:

```
<head>
{% if site.google_verification %}
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="{{ site.google_verification }}">
{% endif %}
<!-- some other code -->
</head>
```